# How to split a field in Microsoft sql server into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, split

I have a table with a column with following entries-

```
Drug
Sertraline 100mg tablets
Phenobarbitol 20mg capsules
```

I want this column to be split into four-

```
Drugname    Strength   Units   Form
Sertraline  100        mg      tablets
```

Could someone please guide me as to who to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are many resources on this online

Comment: Don't write such an entry in the fist place. This is a bad idea in all databases. It breaks even the 1st normal form. If you want to be able to query those values, store them in a separate table

Comment: Yes. I tried LEFT and SUBSTRING. But am not quite getting what I want.

Comment: You can try STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2016, but it's a LOT easier to clean up the data when inserting it. SQL isn't the best language for string manipulation and definitely unsuitable for parsing.

Comment: I guess you have a lot of data and in each case the format could be different. So we could write something for that data but it won't work other data.

Comment: If you have a late enough version of SQL Server then you can use the `string_split` function to extract most of it.

Comment: Yes. I understand but I have no control on entering the data into the database. Someone else has done this..

Answer (score 3):

With a little XML and and CROSS APPLY

The pattern is clear and easy to expand or contract as needed

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[Drug],' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as B1
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Pos1            Pos2    Pos3        Pos4    Pos5
Sertraline      100mg   tablets     NULL    NULL
Phenobarbitol   20mg    capsules    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

An one more suggestion:

The first CTE transforms your CSV string to an XML, which allows to address each part separately.
The second CTE retrieves the three parts.
The final `SELECT` uses some string methods to separate strength and unit.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Drug VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('Sertraline 100mg tablets')
                      ,('Phenobarbitol 20mg capsules');
WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT Drug AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Casted
    FROM @tbl 
)
,Parts AS
(
    SELECT Casted.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Drugname
          ,Casted.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS CombinedStrenthUnit
          ,Casted.value('/x[3]/text()[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Form
    FROM Splitted
)
SELECT *
      ,LEFT(CombinedStrenthUnit,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',CombinedStrenthUnit)-1) AS Strength 
      ,SUBSTRING(CombinedStrenthUnit,PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%',CombinedStrenthUnit),1000) AS Unit
FROM Parts;
```

The result

```
Drugname        S&U     Form        Strength    Unit
Sertraline      100mg   tablets     100         mg
Phenobarbitol   20mg    capsules    20          mg
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a [user-defined split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) for splitting text into 3 pieces seperated by space character as follows

Of course if you have SQL Server 2016 or later then you can use [STRING_SPLIT](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx) SQL function too

```
with rawdata as (
    select rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by txt), * from drugs
), cte as (
select
    rn,
    d.txt,
    s.id,
    s.val
from rawdata d
cross apply dbo.Split(rtrim(ltrim(d.txt)),' ') s
)
select * from cte
```

Please note that the Row_Number rn column is required to identify each row in following script. If you have a PK field in your source table, instead of using rn field created by Row_Number function, you can directly use those Primary Key fields

And to split the second column (strength and units), I again preferred to use custom SQL functions; [ClearNumericCharacters](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/remove-numeric-characters-in-string-using-sql.aspx) and [ClearNonNumericCharacters](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/remove-non-numeric-characters-in-sql-string-expression.aspx)
Of course you can use inline functions or RegExp instead of UDFs

Here is the final SQL CTE expression

```
with rawdata as (
    select rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by txt), * from drugs
), cte as (
select
    rn,
    d.txt,
    s.id,
    s.val
from rawdata d
cross apply dbo.Split(rtrim(ltrim(d.txt)),' ') s
), cte2 as (
select
rn,
case when id = 1 then val end as Drugname,
case when id = 2 then dbo.ClearNonNumericCharacters(val) end as Strength,
case when id = 2 then dbo.ClearNumericCharacters(val) end as Units,
case when id = 3 then val end as Form
from cte
)
select
    max(Drugname) Drugname,
    max(Strength) Strength,
    max(Units) Units,
    max(Form) Form
from cte2
group by rn
```

And the output is

[image]